# Ionic 4 Google place autocomplete using Reactive- Form

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm tying to use googlemap places API for autoComplete in my project, but it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInputElement' of undefined
```

.html

```
<section
          [formGroupName]="i"
          *ngFor="let tech of form.controls.technologies.controls; let i = index">
          <ion-item-group>
              <ion-item-divider color="light">Station #{{ i + 1 }}</ion-item-divider>

             <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="floating">Technology name:</ion-label>
                <ion-input
                   #autoCompleteStation
                   type="text"
                   maxlength="50"
                   formControlName="name"></ion-input>
             </ion-item>



          </ion-item-group>
       </section>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteStation', {static: true}) autoCompleteStation: any;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.autoCompleteStation.getInputElement().then((input:HTMLInputElement)=>{
        var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {

          //somee code
     });

    }
   });
```

PS:
when I remove the for loop it works, but when I add it again it gives the error above.
any suggestions please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add a text field with google places dynamically using ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234719/how-to-add-a-text-field-with-google-places-dynamically-using-ionic-4)