# google places api doesnt work for the generated text field using ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic4

the code below is used to add text field dynamicaly, this text fiels is a goole places autocomplete list, my problem is the goole places api works just for the first field and doesnt work . for the generated fields

.html

```
<section
          [formGroupName]="i"
          *ngFor="let tech of form.controls.stations.controls; let i = index">


             <ion-button
             (click)="removeInputField(i)"
             *ngIf="form.controls.technologies.length > 1"
              class="ion-no-padding ion-float-right" shape="round" fill="clear">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="close"></ion-icon>Remove</ion-button>


          </ion-item-group>
       </section>
       <div>
           <!-- Allow new input field to be generated/added -->

    <ion-button
    (click)="addNewInputField()"

     class="ion-no-padding ion-float-left" shape="round" fill="clear">
       <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon> Add a new technology</ion-button>
       </div>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('autoStation', {static: true}) autoStation: any;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.autoCompleteStation.forEach( autoStation => {
       autoStation.getInputElement().then(( input: HTMLInputElement) => {
          var autocompl = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {

          //somee code
     });

    }
   });
     addNewInputField() : void {
      const control =  this.form.controls.technologies as FormArray;


       control.push(this.initTechnologyFields());
       }

  removeInputField(i : number) : void {
    const control =  this.form.controls.technologies as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(i);
   }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I added some pictures to have a rough idea about the problem, the first pic you see the UI which I made the second one When when Tried to typing a city google places api is working but when I click the button to add new city the text field is generated but the google places api doesnt work, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening in your code:

1. the reason places API works for the ion-inputs that are already in your component's template created via *ngFor is simple - in your components' ngAfterViewInit lifecycle you have a method that runs across all those ion-inputs, obtains their native input element and initializes Places API for each of them.
2. When you add a new ion-input using the button - there is nothing that helps to initialize places API for those newly added to DOM inputs.

To fix the #2 you need to ensure such newly added ion-input to the DOM gets places API initialized.

If you followed my answer for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234719/how-to-add-a-text-field-with-google-places-dynamically-using-ionic-4/59238063?noredirect=1#comment104768579_59238063) you were using ViewChildren and QueryList, which [according to Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) is used to:

> ...get the QueryList of elements or directives from the view DOM. Any
>   time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will
>   be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a
>   new value.

If so that means in your code you have:

```
@ViewChildren('autoStation') autoStationList:QueryList<any>;
```

this autoStationList gets updated each time you add another ion-input with #autostation identifier.

Which means all you need is to get the last child of this QueryList and init Places API for it. You can do that using QueryList's changes() method, which you can subscribe to and each time the list changes - get its "last" element, extract input and initialize places API:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // here you initialize all ion-input's native inputs that exist in DOM at component view initialization stage:
    this.autoCompleteStation.forEach( autoStation => {
       autoStation.getInputElement().then(( input: HTMLInputElement) => {
          let autocompl = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {

          //some code
          })
    });
    // here you subscribe to changes for the list:
    this.autoStationList.changes.subscribe(list => {
        // here we need to use "last" property of the list:
        list.last.getInputElement().then(( input: HTMLInputElement) => {
            var autocompl = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
            //somee code
            })
        })
    }); 


}
```

Comment: that's what i called perfection at wok, thank you very much, in fact it's a messy code I have to manages with, thaks for your help